# Is there a theory of planar figure?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces, polyhedra

Motivation: If you have a cube, then you know that there is a planar figure, consisting of 6 squares, such that if you glue carefully, then you got your cube. Then, can we figure out that whether a given paper (with a specific shape) form a closed surface without boundary or not?

Example: A square (or rectangle) definitely form a torus, if the size of square is suitably big so that you don't have any problems to glue them as in typical topology course.

<strike>Counterexample: However, a trapezoid cannot form a closed surface without boundary, even if it may form a Mobius strip.</strike> It was wrong as in the comment. Thank Rob!

Question: Is there a theory or theorems telling us that whether a given simply connected surface with boundary form a closed surface without boundary only using isometries over the boundaries (not continuous deformation, which was used in topology)? Any recommendation for references are welcome!

Comment: Your question sounds interesting, but isn't very clear. What metric are you using on the boundaries of the simply connected surfaces and what do you mean by "using isometries over the boundaries"? The identification map on the boundary cannot be an isometry as it identifies distinct points.

Comment: @RobArthan I admit that my question isn't very clear; how about restrict all our arguments on R^2 with Euclidean metric? Just suppose a compact simply connected set on R^2. Then, its boundary form a closed curve, whose length is well-defined via Euclidean metric. Then, can we find a gluing map (which do not deform the boundary continuously) such that after glueing we got a closed surface without boundary? What conditions assure that such glueing exist?

Comment: So I think you mean that you can subdivide the boundary into arcs and give isometries between pairs of those arcs that fit together to induce a quotient mapping of the planar figure onto the closed surface. If so, then trapezoids don't provide a counter-example: the vertices of the trapezoid don't have any special properties that prevent you finding a suitable subdivision of its boundary into an appropriate set of arcs (whose endpoints are not all vertices of the trapezoid).

Comment: @RobArthan You right; thank you very much! Then, can we find a counter example? Or just all such simply connected compact set can be a closed surface?

Comment: You need to make a more precise statement. E.g., the simply-connected set could be a point or a line segment. If you restrict to compact surfaces with boundary, then I think you can always find a quotient space that is a closed surface via isometric identifications of arcs in the boundary. (Think of a cat closing its eyes.)

Comment: If you're allowing arbitrary deformation of the interior of the surface (ie the mapping is just continuous), then you can just glue one half of the boundary to the other half. If you're not allowed to deform the interior (ie the mapping should be a local isometry) then your example of a square folding into a torus doesn't work.

Comment: @MartianInvader: the OP seems only to be interested in the metric on the boundary of the original surface. We don't have any information on the metric on the quotient space.

Comment: @RobArthan My point is that if you don't care about preserving the metric on the interior, then the answer to "Which shapes can be folded into a closed surface?" is "All of them".